# How to solve Importing data from my server to apk

Tags: android, import, apk

I have a problem When I try to put my server link in the app code and after I compile it and tried to use the apk in my phone I got message that tells me that it can not import data from the server but despite that all the data is already set in my server.

[image]

Comment: code, error, logcat, etc. that screenshot is not useful to determine the problem

Comment: if you are using your local IP, your phone has to be in the same local network as your server.

Comment: try to debug your code, and see if server is really working , use toasts , logcat ... this screenshot has no utility to resolve the problem ...